# Compare times in SQLite

Tags: android, datetime, sqlite, timestamp

I am using SQLite in Android to store a timeStamp in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`
I would like to compare just the time of the timestamp with some values eg. `HOUR(timestamp)>12` etc. , but HOUR is not a legal function in SQLite. I have changed it as described below and I have something like this: `" where "+" strftime('%H','"+timeStamp+"')>"+time1+" AND strftime('%H','"+timeStamp+"')<'"+time2;` where time1 and time2 are integer between 0-23. I have 7 entries in the table so 7 timestamps. however i get 0 results back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT strftime('%H', 'now');
```

or

```
SELECT strftime('%H', columnName);
```

the output will be 0 to 24

Comment: so how do i include my timestamp?

Comment: BTW: SQLite uses dynamic typing.  If one operand is a REAL or INTEGER it will try to convert TEXT to a number.  You can also use CAST(expr as type)

Comment: thanks.. it does not crash but i get no results back.. i have something like " strftime('%H','"+timeStamp+"')>"+time1+" AND strftime('%H','"+timeStamp+"')<"+time2; where time1 and time2 are integers. e.g time1=0, time2=12

Comment: Can you do a SELECT strftime('%H', columnName);
and look whats the result plz

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamp is in the table you want something like:

```
String time1 = 0;
String time2 = 12;    
String query = "select timestamp from table where strftime('%H',timestamp) < " +
       time1 +
       " and strftime('%H',timeStamp) < " +
       time2 +
       ";";
```

Comment: this is how i have it except the semi colon which is not needed in rawQueries.

Comment: time1 and time2 are Strings or int?

Comment: time1 and time2 can be of type int or String.